# Javascript - changing name of 2d array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input like so

```
<input type="text" name="testingOptions[Food][Burger1]" class="form-control" id="Food">
```

At the moment, I am cloning this input if a checkbox is selected.  Within the clone I do

```
var inputOrgName = clone.find('input').attr('name');
clone.find('input').attr('name', inputOrgName);
```

So this gives the cloned input the same name attribute as the original.  Problem is, I need to add Test on the end of the cloned name.  So I am aiming for something like this

```
<input type="text" name="testingOptions[Food][Burger1Test]" class="form-control" id="Food">
```

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading you're trying to change the name of an input field, not the name of the array (though I understand why you worded it as such). My suggestion would be to use javascript to generate the input field instead of using clone and then trying to rename the newly created field as this causes some headache. Since I'm not answering you're question I won't submit as an answer.

Comment: Also if you clone the input also the id will be duplicate. It's better if you create the input "manually" from javascript.

Comment: what is this `clone` function you are using? when I try to use it, I am getting errors: `Uncaught ReferenceError: clone is not defined(…)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is to change the name of the input field and not the array, And the solution which I think would best suit you is `string replace`.

So modify your code to replace the string by a new string with the word `test` in it. Using regex would be more simpler.

```
clone.find('input').attr('name', inputOrgName.replace(/]$/g,'Test]'));
```

This must get you the desired output.